# Add Open Graph Metatag in backend

Tags: meta-tags

I need to set the og:iamge metatag using the Metatag Module. 
Since there is no option for editing the names of the metatags or adding custom ones, I'm unsure if this is possible.

Is it possible to do this not programatically/from the backend?

Comment: Yes it is, but what have you tried so far? Maybe simply checkout the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module which provides you editable Open Graph meta tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you installed the Metatag and Metatag Open Graph extensions, you need to:

- Go to the metatag configuration page (/admin/config/search/metatag).
- Edit the desired config
- Under the `Open Graph` tab, fill the Image field with the relative path to your image
  [image: Example of Open Graph metatags]
- Save your config.
- When expanding the config you modified, you can see the list of metatags you set (on my example I edited the `Global` configuration). You can see that og_image is in it.
  [image: Result of example Open Graph Metatags]